# How do I use the system() command to pass in user input?

Tags: ruby, shell, command

I want to use `system("insert shell command here")` and pass in a script. This script however, requires user input. I want to pass in the user input as well. How do I do this?

I tried:

```
system('./script')
system('input1')
system('input2')
```

However, Ruby waits till the first system call is done and then only proceeds to go to the next one.

Is it possible to do this? I've tried `system('./script', 'input1')` but that didn't work either.
No luck with `exec` either.

Comment: You want to pipe what the user's input should be into the script? HOW is that script retrieving the input? If it's an authentication, that will usually fail because password inputs are usually accepted only from the TTY or KBD device, not STDIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into the [Open3 library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) from the Ruby stdlib. It gives you more control over "shelling out".

```
output, status = Open3.capture2("./script", :stdin_data => "I am STDIN")
```

Comment: Hmm okay, but this isn't possible without the use of external libraries?

Comment: What external libraries? Open3 is part of Ruby.

Comment: This *should* work, unless the script being called is doing authentication, then the OP is SOL unless there's a way to spoof the input as coming from the KBD or TTY devices.

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin env ruby

input1 = ARGV[0]
input2 = ARGV[1]

system("./script #{input1} #{input2}")
```

Comment: What happens when `ARGV[0]` is `; rm -rf /`? Please don't try that to see what it does.

Comment: good point. yeah got to be careful with that. can put an if condition so as to avoid rm -rf / commands. The rule of the thumb is define what will be acceptable and then refuse everything else. Can also have a look at Shellwords.escape

Comment: Why bother with all that when [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) can bypass the shell completely? String interpolation for building `system` commands is almost never a good idea, just like using string interpolation for SQL is almost never a good idea.

Comment: this would pass in the inputs as arguments. However, the script doesn't take in any arguments. Instead it runs through and asks for user input for certain variables periodically and those are the ones I want to fill in