# How do I start a bat file and enter a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a rails application that needs to run a bat file and enter a password.
Tell me, how can this be done? Thank you!
The bat file:

```
SET JAVA_HOME=C:\javahome
if NOT DEFINED var (set /P var="password: ")
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code. Also, that's not even a screenshot of the code. Please just post the code. If is contains sensitive information, feel free to redact it as needed -- but we need to see a [mcve] of the problem in order to answer it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518465/auto-input-password-in-batchfile-cmd-file

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17957006/6014860) should help you. That should work for Windows too.

Use Open3 like this:

`output, status = Open3.capture2("script.bat", :stdin_data => my_secret_password)`